# How do you access file contents of a form selected file in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, forms

I need to take a .csv file from an HTML form and parse through all the data.

Right now I am using the CSV gem in a ruby script to parse a local file and post it to a Pardot form handler with this code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'csv'

uri = URI('<form handler url>')

CSV.foreach("<csv file location>", :headers => :first_row) do |row|
  res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri,    'city' => row['city'],
                                'state' => row['state'],
                                'zip' => row['zip'],
                                'country' => row['country'],
                                'phone' => row['phone'],
                                'fax' => row['fax'],
                                'website' => row['website'],
                                'first_name' => row['first_name'],
                                'last_name' => row['last_name'],
                                'job_title' => row['job_title'],
                                'Company' => row['Company'],
                                'leadtype' => row['leadtype'],
                                'tradeshow_attended' => row['tradeshow_attended'],
                                'industry' => row['industry'],
                                'email' => row['email'],
                                'boothsize' => row['boothsize'],
                                'company' => row['company'],
                                'source' => row['source'],
                                'address_one' => row['address_one'],
                                'address_two' => row['address_two']
                                )
end
```

Now I have created a Sinatra site with a simple form that has a text input for url and a file upload for the csv file.

What I want to do is pull the CSV file's data into the script above.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <p>
                    <label>Form Handler URL</label><input name="url" type="text"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Please specify a file</label>
                    <input type="file" name="datafile">
                </p>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
```

I can get the file information using

```
params[:datafile]
```

**How do I get the text of a file uploaded through this form?**  The file is not going to be saved on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it so happens the file is already saved on the server (albeit to a temporary file as a tempfile object). you can access it through `:tempfile` in the params-hash:

```
content = params[:datafile][:tempfile].read
```